# Difference between writing an event in code behind over source in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

What is the difference between writing an onclick event in source page and in code behind.

.cs Page:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     this.BtnReset.Click += new EventHandler(this.BtnReset_Click);
     this.BtnSave.Click += new EventHandler(this.BtnSave_Click);
}
```

.aspx Page:

```
 <asp:Button Text="Save" runat="server" ID="BtnSave" Onclick="BtnSave_Click" />
 <asp:Button Text="Reset" runat="server" ID="BtnReset" Onclick="BtnReset_Click" />
```

Both seems to be same. Is there any performance advantage in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not performance advantage on this. its just bind click event with the perticalur event handler even you do in page or in code behind

Answer (score 1):

Doing it in code behind, to me feels a neat way!
No performance difference in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

There is no sensible performance advantage using the first or the second.

I prefer the second one because you can unwire an event without recompiling the whole web application and it's more compact and readable.

Just some notes:

1. Premature optimization is evil
2. Performance problems usually come from database access, I/O, Threading and bad algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge there is no deference.. only thing is if you write it in your code behind file you  have more control over it.